# Vim - indent and syntax highlight broken after recover file

Tags: vim, syntax, highlight, recover

I was editing a file with vim. I started another vim to edit the same file, it said that the /tmp/file.swp exits, press "R" to recover it. I chose to recover. But after that, syntax highlight didn't work on that file (other files still ok). I tried :syntax on and some commands but not worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try to use the following command to specify the type type. For example for c file:

```
:set filetype=c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you explain why this happened despite running the swp file recovery.

Answer (score 2):

I just solve it, in a simple way.

I find the folder which ~/.vim/view/ and remove the record about the py file which i just recovered...

```
cd ~/.vim/view && ls -alh | grep filename_1 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
```

You can change that as you like ... just a demo.

:)

Answer (score 1):

I had to recover a vim buffer after a sudden crash. Whilst the file was correctly recovered, I could not say the same for the syntax highlighting. (I am pretty sure this is not language-dependent, but for completeness sake my file was a python script.)

To my knowledge this issue is often due to either sessions, as [stated in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281438/syntax-highlighting-doesnt-work-after-restore-a-previous-vim-session), or syntax highlighting which was incorrectly loaded. However [vim views](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#views-sessions) also affect how the file is displayed in the editor. This is especially true for those, like me, who tend to [automatise the loading of previously stored views](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_views_automatic). Following this hunch **I deleted my stored view file** and solved the problem.

Please note this solution obviously comes at a cost: *the file will be opened with a fresh view*, i.e. no previous layouts (cursor position, opened/closed fols, etc.) will be remembered by vim. This is pretty obvious but I thought I'd mention it nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Might need to set the file type for the correct syntax:

```
" C syntax:
:set ft=c

" Java syntax:
:set ft=java

" Python syntax:
:set ft=py

" ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-run the buffer open process to run all autocommands again by typing `:e %` which edits the current file. This will make all bufread* auto commands run and you'll get everything back. I believe they are deliberately disabled in case there's something bad in the recovered file and custom autocommands may do something bad with a corrupted file.